# How to grep a Line and update a particular column value

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

I have to update a particular column value in a file for particular Unique IDs.
My file-name and  sample contents are given below:

**Names.txt**

```
J017 0001 Amit 10th
J011 2341 Kuldeep 11th
J004 1254 Ramand  12th
```

I have to update the 4th column value to something . I tried the below logic but did not work

```
stu="";
for i in `echo "J017, J058 and J107.  " |egrep -o '[jJ][0-9]{3}' `
do
   stu="$stu|$i ";
   awk -v I=$i '/$I/{$4="LEFT";print $0}'  Names.txt >tmp
done


egrep -v `echo "$stu" | sed "s/^|//g" ` Names.txt >>tmp

mv tmp Names.txt
```

The above awk command did not give the result. Please help me to fix the error.

Comment: Though I have work out another way to get the result, but I want to find out error in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? How is your column modified?

Comment: Your posted script clearly is not going to work. What values are you using to update the 4th column in `Names.txt`?

Comment: @anubhava I am updating the values to "Left"in the 4th column

Comment: instead of variable If I am directly using the value it is working in awk , the only problem is in using the variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your specific question about why this:

```
awk -v I=$i '/$I/{$4="LEFT";print $0}'
```

doesn't work, you don;t acces awk variables by prefixing them with a "$", just like you don't do that for C or most other languages (shell being an exception). This is how you would write the above to execute the way you are trying to get it to execute:

```
awk -v I=$i '$0 ~ I{$4="LEFT";print $0}'
```

Having said that, your shell script is completely the wrong way to do what you want. Try this instead (uses GNU awk for patsplit() but match()/substr() in other awks would work just as well):

```
$ cat tst.sh
awk -v ids="J017, J058 and J107.  " '
BEGIN{
    patsplit(ids,idsA,/[jJ][0-9]{3}/)
    for (i=1;i in idsA;i++)
        stu = stu (i==1?"^":"|") idsA[i]
    stu = stu "$"
}
$1 ~ stu { $4 = "LEFT" }
{ print }
' "$@"

$ ./tst.sh file
J017 0001 Jagdeep LEFT
J011 2341 Kuldeep 11th
J004 1254 Ramand  12th
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying , the query is working now.

I could not understand what performance issue or wrong approach my script is having , can You help regarding that ..

Comment: Your goal is to manipulate the contents of a text file. shell was created to create/destroy processes and files and sequence calls to UNIX tools. awk is the general purpose UNIX tool created to manipulate text files and is available on all UNIX installations. Your shell script as well as being non-functional was long, complicated, buggy, non-portable, resource-intensive and slow due to you using the wrong tool for the job. EVERY time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate the contents of a text file, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE='Names.txt'    
COLUMNS=(J017 J011 J004)
REPLACE='LEFT'

OUT=$(
    IFS="|"
    awk -v R="$REPLACE" -v E="${COLUMNS[*]}" '$1 ~ E{$4 = R;print $0}' "$FILE"
)

echo "$OUT" > "$FILE"
```

Run with:

```
bash script.sh
```

Input:

```
J017 0001 Jagdeep 10th
J011 2341 Kuldeep 11th
J004 1254 Ramand  12th
```

Result:

```
J017 0001 Jagdeep LEFT
J011 2341 Kuldeep LEFT
J004 1254 Ramand LEFT
```

Comment: Thanks for your help 
BUt can you help to find out the error in my script
because instead of variable If I am directly using the value it is working , the only problem is in using the variable

Answer (score 0):

Names.txt

```
J017 0001 Jagdeep 10th
J011 2341 Kuldeep 11th
J004 1254 Ramand  12th
```

awk

```
awk '/[jJ][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ {$4="LEFT"}1' Names.txt
J017 0001 Jagdeep LEFT
J011 2341 Kuldeep LEFT
J004 1254 Ramand LEFT
```

Comment: I do not have to replace every value , but some specific values like out of 3 values it could be J011 and the file may contain 1000 entries , so I need the general solution

Thanks for your help ..

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "J017, J111 and J004.  " |
grep -o "J[0-9]\{3\}" |
awk 'FNR==NR{key[$1];next};$1 in key{$4="LEFT"}1' - Names.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for replying 
it is not working .
I am curious about finding the flaws in my own query used to grep the result